# Bun run does nothing but echo the command

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tauri, bun

I'm currently trying to create a Tauri app using Bun in WSL. Using `bun create tauri-app`:

```
✔ Project name · test
✔ Choose which language to use for your frontend · TypeScript / JavaScript - (pnpm, yarn, npm, bun)
✔ Choose your package manager · bun
✔ Choose your UI template · Vanilla
✔ Choose your UI flavor · TypeScript

Template created! To get started run:
  cd test
  bun install
  bun run tauri dev
```

Following these commands, `bun run tauri dev` just echos `tauri dev`

```
root@DESKTOP-FOOBAR/some/path/test# bun run tauri dev
$ tauri dev
root@DESKTOP-FOOBAR/some/path/test#
```

Nothing actually happens. After a few seconds of waiting, it sends me back to the terminal command line input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run Tauri's frontend without `npm` use this command:

```bash
bunx --bun vite
```

And then run the `rust` backend part:

```bash
cd src-tauri
cargo run
```

I wrote on this topic a little more here [at the end](https://www.developermindset.com/how-to-run-tauri-without-vite/).

Comment: If you haven't already, I would suggest reading the page on [promotion](/help/promotion). You did everything right in this answer; I just want to make sure it stays that way because I see *way* too many people linking their own sites the wrong way. The main points are to always disclose your affiliation, make sure the answer would be useful without the link to your page, and of course don't link your site in every answer. Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks Jesse, appreciate the heads up!